# Can I use retain with ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I was reading this official guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW13 and I'm not sure if it's referring to old ways of dealing with reference counting or is just for demonstration how it works - but should one use retain/release manually like in example with accessors?

Comment: If you are new to ARC then you should have a look at the ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: yes I know, was just unsure of purpose for stating this in official doc (educational or real life), but thanks for link, will take a look :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to use `retain` with ARC. However it still works the same in the background as without ARC (and as described in that documentation you linked), but the `retain` and `release` calls are added by the compiler as necessary. You don't have to deal with that.

This setter:

```
- (void)setCount:(NSNumber *)newCount {
    [newCount retain];
    [_count release];
    // Make the new assignment.
    _count = newCount;
}
```

should look like this, when using ARC:

```
- (void)setCount:(NSNumber *)newCount {
    // Make the new assignment.
    _count = newCount;
}
```

Comment: +1 And to be clear, @raistlin, Apple's not suggesting you write this code (because 99% of the time, you use the automatically synthesized accessor methods), but just showing you what it does. And from that perspective, seeing what the equivalent non-ARC code does is more illustrative of what's going on behind the scenes than ARC code would be.

Comment: Yes. You only need to manually implement a setter, if you want to do something when that property changes. For instance to redraw your view or reload a table.

Answer (score 1):

**you not use retain with ARC but** 
It is possible to disable ARC for individual files by adding the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for those files.

You add compiler flags in Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. You have to double click on the right column of the row under Compiler Flags. You can also add it to multiple files by holding the cmd button to select the files and then pressing enter to bring up the flag edit box.[image]

Comment: yes, I know I can disable ARC for some files. I was just curious if - despite stating here and there in official guides about ARC - it's in Apple's doc just for educational or real life usage purpose